# Unable to generate plot from dccfit (R)

Tags: plot

R version: 3.4.2

I'm using rugarch and mgarch to spec and fit model with DCC to my data.  The model is generated successfully, however I'm unable to generate the plots.  Here's a snippet of my code:

```
library(rugarch)
library(rmgarch)
da=read.table("d-msft3dx0113.txt",header=T)
MSFT.ret = da[,3]
GSPC.ret = da[,6]
MSFT.GSPC.ret = cbind(MSFT.ret,GSPC.ret)

garch11.spec = ugarchspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0,0)), 
                      variance.model = list(garchOrder = c(1,1), 
                                            model = "sGARCH"), 
                      distribution.model = "norm")

dcc.garch11.spec = dccspec(uspec = multispec( replicate(2, garch11.spec) ), 
                       dccOrder = c(1,1), 
                       distribution = "mvnorm")

dcc.fit = dccfit(dcc.garch11.spec, data = MSFT.GSPC.ret)
dcc.fcst = dccforecast(dcc.fit, n.ahead=100)

plot(dcc.fcst)
```

When I call for plot, I get this error:

```
plot(dcc.fcst)
```

Make a plot selection (or 0 to exit):

1. Conditional Mean Forecast  (vs realized  returns)
2. Conditional Sigma Forecast (vs realized |returns|)
3. Conditional Covariance Forecast
4. Conditional Correlation Forecast
5. EW Portfolio Plot with forecast conditional density VaR limits

Selection: 1

> Error in int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf, ...) :
>     plot.new has not been called yet

I then give it a new plot area:

```
plot.new()
plot(dcc.fcst)
```

Which gives me this unhelpful plot:

[Selection1Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCMwq.png)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question, too. I don't know why `plot(dcc.fic)` cannot work. So I do it manually to extract the correlation and covariance. `rcov` and `rcor` are two functions to extract what we need.

```
plot(rcov(dcc.fit)[1,2,], type = "l", col = "blue", 
     main = "Conditional Covariance", xlab = "Time", 
     ylab = "Covariance")
plot(rcor(dcc.fit)[1,2,], type = "l", col = "purple", 
     main = "Conditional Correlation", xlab = "Time", 
     ylab = "Correlation")
```

Comment: Yes, I ended up doing something similar.  However, I could not find/extract the prediction intervals on the forecast... not sure if they're even included in the forecast output.